# Citing in the form "(Name, Year)"

Tags: bibliographies, citing

Im currently writing a paper with the iop/emulateapj template (http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~alexey/emulateapj/). I want the following citation style to work:

> Defining what life is is a complex matter (Smith, 2012). However, the work of Anderson et al. (2013) models life as a random walk, with successful applications to the social sciences.

However, what I get instead is this:

> Defining what life is is a complex matter (Smith 2012). However, the work of Anderson et al. (2013) models life as a random walk, with successful applications to the social sciences.

Note that the comma after the citation to Smith's work is what I want. My bibliography looks like this:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem[Anderson et al.(2013)]{And13} Anderson, T., 2012, Journal of Life, 
289, pp. 1209-1250.
\bibitem[Smith(2012)]{Smith12} Smith, H., 2012, Journal of The Matrix, 
143, pp. 313-320.
\end{thebibliography}
```

And my code in that part of the LaTeX code looks like this:

```
Defining what life is is a complex matter \citep{Smith2012}. However, the work of 
\citet{And13} models life as a random walk, with successful applications 
to the social sciences.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: are you open to using `biblatex`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file `emulateapj.cls` contains the following lines:

```
\renewcommand{\bibstyle@aas}{\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{}{,}}% 
\citestyle{aas}
```

which show that the coma won't be used to separate the author from the year (the fifth argument of `\bibpunct` is empty). To revert to the coma, redefine the `aas` bibstyle:

```
\documentclass[iop]{emulateapj}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\bibstyle@aas}{\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}}% 
\citestyle{aas}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Defining what life is is a complex matter \citep{Smith12}. However, the work of 
\citet{And13} models life as a random walk, with successful applications 
to the social sciences.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem[Anderson et al.(2013)]{And13} Anderson, T., 2012, Journal of Life, 
289, pp. 1209-1250.
\bibitem[Smith(2012)]{Smith12} Smith, H., 2012, Journal of The Matrix, 
143, pp. 313-320.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]